# Generic CRUD API client with Typescript and Axios

Tags: typescript, axios

I'm trying to implement a generic CRUD interface for my API in Typescript using Axios.

Suppose the API exposes endpoints for doing CRUD operations with 2 entities. Say the endpoints are `/users` and `/posts/` and both take URL parameters `offset` and `count` (for pagination). Example of responses:

```
GET /users?offset=2&count=2

{
  "users": ["user1", "user2"],
  "total": 4 // the total number of users that exist
}
```

and similarly for `posts` instead the key for the array of posts is `"posts".

I tried to create a generic function to get either of users/posts as follows:

```js
export const getPage =
  async <T extends Persistable>(offset: number, count: number): Promise<PaginatedResponse<T>> => {
    const response = await axios.get<PaginatedResponse<T>>(
      `${SOME_URL}/<BLANK>`,
      {
        params: { page, size },
        transformResponse: [
          (data) => ({
            ...data,
            items: data[<BLANK>],
          })
        ]
      },
    );
    return response.data;
  };
```

Where `Persistable` interface that both `User` and `Post` interfaces inherit from and `PaginatedResponse` interface looks as follows:

```js
export interface PaginatedResponse<T> {
  readonly total: number;
  readonly items: T[];
}
```

Basically, I'd need to fill in the `<BLANK>`s by e.g. somehow getting strings `"users"`/`"posts"` respectively based on the passed type `T`.

Can anyone think of a way to achieve this, please?

Comment: The type system in TypeScript is compile-time only, there's no representation of it at run-time that you can assert on to determine this. You would need to fall back to a standard JavaScript way of doing it which might be, if you're using constructor functions for example, to use the `name` property of the constructor. Other options might be just setting a property yourself with the value or doing some structural comparison of the object to determine its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may suggest following solution using function overloading. I don't recomment using generics in this situation as `T` is limited to either `user` or `post`. As TypeScript interface is about shape, with generics `T` can be virtually anything that extends `Persistable`

I have imagined that users and posts will not be array of strings, but array of objects. `type` property will create [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) and will stay after compilation.

I've added additional argument `reqType` to `getPage` function to distinguish between users and posts request. `reqType` may be either `'user'` or `'post'`. Other values will lead to error.

This `User['type']` is [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types), so if you'll add another type of response in future, reqType will be populated with `type` value automatically.

```
type User = { type: 'user', user: string };
type Post = { type: 'post', post: string };

export interface PaginatedResponse<T> {
    readonly total: number;
    readonly items: T[];
}

// This is type guard which will stay in run time
function reqTypeIsUser(a: User['type'] | Post['type']): a is User['type'] {
    return (a as User['type']) === 'user'
}

async function getPage
    (offset: number, count: number, reqType: User['type']): Promise<PaginatedResponse<User>>
async function getPage
    (offset: number, count: number, reqType: Post['type']): Promise<PaginatedResponse<Post>>
async function getPage
    (offset: number, count: number, reqType: User['type'] | Post['type']): Promise<PaginatedResponse<User | Post>> {

        const response = await axios.get<PaginatedResponse<User | Post>>(
            'url' + reqTypeIsUser(reqType) ? 'users' : 'posts',
            {
                params: { offset, count },
                transformResponse: [
                    (data) => ({
                        ...data,
                        items: data[reqType].map((d: string) => ({ type: reqType, [reqType]: d })),
                      })
                    ]
                  },
                );
                return response.data;
};

let user = getPage(1, 2, "user");  // user will be Promise<PaginatedResponse<User>>
```